# Storing text that includes html tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I have strings that I want to store in and object. Some of the text in the strings requires special formatting, specifically it must be subscript. I have tried simply writing the element tags. Tags show up on page when displayed. I created a variable saved the tags there appended the content to the variable, sub element has no effect. Tried adding .innerHTML to variable, still no joy. Any idea's.

```js
var quizDiv = document.createElement("div")
  //gives from element and id attribute
quizDiv.setAttribute("id", "airspeedIndicatorQuiz")
  //retreives element on page inwhitch to place form and saves it in variable
var makeNewPage = document.getElementById("newPage")
  //appentds input form to makeNewPage
makeNewPage.appendChild(quizDiv)

//creat sub element and store in variable vso
var vso = document.createElement("sub")
  //creat text node and store in variable vsoText
var vsoText = document.createTextNode("SO")
  //append vsoText to vso
vso.appendChild(vsoText)

console.log(vso)
var aIMakingsObj = [{
  marking: "White arc",
  meaning: "Flap oparating range"
}, {
  marking: "V" + vso.innerHTML + " Lower A/S Limit White Arc",
  meaning: "Stall speed landing configuration"
}, {
  marking: "V<sub>FE</sub> Upper A/S Limit White Arc",
  meaning: "Maximum flap extention speed"
}, {
  marking: "Green Arc",
  meaning: "Normal Oparating Range"
}, {
  marking: "V" + '<sub>S1</sub>' + " Lower A/S Limit Green Arc",
  meaning: "Maximum flap extention speed"
}, {
  marking: "V<sub>NO</sub> Upper A/S Limit Green Arc",
  meaning: "Maximum structural cruse speed"
}, {
  marking: "Yellow Arc",
  meaning: "Caution Range (oparations in smooth air only)"
}, {
  marking: "V" + '<sub>NE</sub>' + " Red Line",
  meaning: "never exceed speed; above this speed structural failure may occure"
}]

displayQuiz()

function displayQuiz() {


  for (i = 0; i < aIMakingsObj.length; i++) {


    var aPool = document.createElement("p")
    var aPoolTex = document.createTextNode(aIMakingsObj[i].marking)
    aPool.appendChild(aPoolTex)
    makeNewPage.appendChild(aPool)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body id="newPage">




  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

innerHTML seems to be working.

```js
var quizDiv = document.createElement("div")
  //gives from element and id attribute
quizDiv.setAttribute("id", "airspeedIndicatorQuiz")
  //retreives element on page inwhitch to place form and saves it in variable
var makeNewPage = document.getElementById("newPage")
  //appentds input form to makeNewPage
makeNewPage.appendChild(quizDiv)

//creat sub element and store in variable vso
var vso = document.createElement("sub")
  //creat text node and store in variable vsoText
var vsoText = document.createTextNode("SO")
  //append vsoText to vso
vso.appendChild(vsoText)

console.log(vso)
var aIMakingsObj = [{
  marking: "White arc",
  meaning: "Flap oparating range"
}, {
  marking: "V" + vso.innerHTML + " Lower A/S Limit White Arc",
  meaning: "Stall speed landing configuration"
}, {
  marking: "V<sub>FE</sub> Upper A/S Limit White Arc",
  meaning: "Maximum flap extention speed"
}, {
  marking: "Green Arc",
  meaning: "Normal Oparating Range"
}, {
  marking: "V" + '<sub>S1</sub>' + " Lower A/S Limit Green Arc",
  meaning: "Maximum flap extention speed"
}, {
  marking: "V<sub>NO</sub> Upper A/S Limit Green Arc",
  meaning: "Maximum structural cruse speed"
}, {
  marking: "Yellow Arc",
  meaning: "Caution Range (oparations in smooth air only)"
}, {
  marking: "V" + '<sub>NE</sub>' + " Red Line",
  meaning: "never exceed speed; above this speed structural failure may occure"
}]

displayQuiz()

function displayQuiz() {


  for (i = 0; i < aIMakingsObj.length; i++) {
    var aPool = document.createElement("p");
    aPool.innerHTML = aIMakingsObj[i].marking; // modified
    makeNewPage.appendChild(aPool)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body id="newPage">




  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mikey, thanks for looking at it. The problem with the .innerHTML solution is that Im unable to style the subscript on the web page. It does not include the sub element tag in the HTML. Any other thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by you are unable to style the subscript using `innerHTML()`? Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/09jsbdth/) where `<sub/>` is styled.

Comment: Ha!, Thank you. Your right. Not sure yet why it's not working on my computer but at least now I know it works.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark the answer as solved :)

Comment: Mikey, I was missing the modification you made. Now its working. Your a genius. Thank you